# How to connect mysql-client to my spring boot app

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, google-compute-engine

I have jar file of springboot and I'm running on compute engineVM
And I also connect SQL-client but what address of mysql should I give in spring boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using GCP's hosted mysql? (Cloud SQL).

If so, then if you are connecting to it via cloud sql proxy, which is running on the same machine, then you just use localhost. The proxy should know the way to the server from there, assuming that you've configured the instance name and project/etc. correctly.

Otherwise, without the proxy, you can use your SQL instance's public IP address, which you can see on the list of running instances when you select the SQL page.

In the second case (using the actual IP address) keep in mind that GCP probably wont let the VM running your application through the firewall to the SQl instance directly. To work around this, you'd have to list your VM's IP address in the Authorized Networks section of the SQL entry (click on your SQL instance in the list and select the Authorization tab). Again, in this case, you need to keep in mind that your VM's IP address is ephemeral by default (unless you made and effort to make it permanent). So if you restart your VM, the above Authorization will no longer make sense. So make sure you make your VM's IP address permanent.